# Combining the values of the two columns upon which 'outer' 'merge'-ing is applied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to perform a`pd.merge` with an `outer` manner upon two columns. But I need the output dataframe to have the two columns actually merged together, so that there are no Nan values.

I give an example. Assume the following dataframes that will merge on the timestamp columns:

```
a1=['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-09-01 01:00:00', '2019-09-01 03:00:00', '2019-09-10 01:00:00']
a2=['a','c_1','d','f_1']
b1=['2019-09-01 00:10:00', '2019-09-01 01:00:00', '2019-09-01 03:07:00', '2019-09-10 01:00:00']
b2=['b','c_2', 'e', 'f_2']
A=pd.DataFrame({'a1':a1, 'a2':a2})
A.a1=pd.to_datetime(A.a1)
B=pd.DataFrame({'b1':b1, 'b2':b2})
B.b1=pd.to_datetime(B.b1)
```

The merged dataframe I wish to get is close to this:

```
merged=pd.merge(A,B, left_on='a1', right_on='b1', how='outer', sort=True)
print(merged)
>>>
                   a1   a2                  b1   b2
0 2019-09-01 00:00:00    a                 NaT  NaN
1                 NaT  NaN 2019-09-01 00:10:00    b
2 2019-09-01 01:00:00  c_1 2019-09-01 01:00:00  c_2
3 2019-09-01 03:00:00    d                 NaT  NaN
4                 NaT  NaN 2019-09-01 03:07:00    e
5 2019-09-10 01:00:00  f_1 2019-09-10 01:00:00  f_2
```

except that the desired output should have 'a1' and 'b1' merged. It should look like:

```
             datetime   a2    b2  #datetime column has 'a1' and 'b1' merged
0 2019-09-01 00:00:00    a   NaN
1 2019-09-01 00:10:00  NaN     b
2 2019-09-01 01:00:00  c_1   c_2
3 2019-09-01 03:00:00    d   NaN
4 2019-09-01 03:07:00  NaN     e
5 2019-09-10 01:00:00  f_1   f_2
```

Any thoughts how I can perform that in pythonic/pandaic way?

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas' `combine_first` function after the merge:

```
merged['datetime'] = merged['a1'].combine_first(merged['b1'])
```

Which will take the value of `a1`, and if that's `na`, then the value of `b1`

Comment: It kinda worked.
It created the desired column as an extra column at the end of the dataframe, so I guess I should then drop the 'a1' and 'b1' columns.
Nice to learn the `pandas.combine_first()` method, but I thought that pandas could have provided for such a function within the `pandas.merge()` method.